# CocoaPods Swift Linker Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, llvm, cocoapods

I am trying to use the Loggly libraries through Lumberjack in an iOS application written in Swift. I am getting the following linker errors:

```
undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_LogglyFormatter", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo15LogglyFormatter in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_LogglyLogger", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo12LogglyLogger in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have it using a bridging header for some other libraries (not pod ones) that work just fine.

Here is the contents of my bridging header:

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
#import <CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h>
#import <LogglyLogger-CocoaLumberjack/LogglyLogger.h>
#import <LogglyLogger-CocoaLumberjack/LogglyFormatter.h>
```

Lastly here is the contents of my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'LogglyLogger-CocoaLumberjack', :git => 'https://github.com/melke/LogglyLogger-CocoaLumberjack'
```

Anybody have a suggestion on this?

Comment: I solved this by taking the code and directly integrating it into the project. This defeats the purpose of pods, but it worked. So still looking for a proper solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

As of Cocoapods 0.25.0 the Xcode configuration maintains that the Pods are built with build setting `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` set to YES. You have two options:

1. Make sure you set "Build Active Architecture" to YES for your Debug configuration
2. Set Build Active Architecture to NO for the cocoapods in the Debug configuration

So assuming you did option 1, navigate to your build settings and you should end up with something like this:

[image]

Included from the official [Troubleshooting Guide](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html)

> This applies to users migrating projects from Xcode 4, or are still
>   using Xcode 4.
>
> 1. The Pods Xcode project now sets the ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH build setting to
>      YES in the Debug configuration. You will have to set the same on your
>      project/target, otherwise the build will fail.
> 2. Ensure your
>      project/target has an ARCHS value set, otherwise the build will fail.
> 3. When building a iOS project from the command-line, with the xcodebuild
>      tool that comes with Xcode 4, you’ll need to completely disable this
>      setting by appending to your build command: ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO.

Comment: It was already set correctly and even flipping them isn't working either.

Comment: @Khirok does cocoa lumberjack support 64 bit targets? If you build to iPhone 5 for instance does it work?

Comment: Same thing if I compile to the iPhone 5. I have used it on apps in Obj-C before on my 5S, so I know it works there. This just seems to be a weird issue with the linking using a bridged header.